# Como eu posso saber se uma fonte é livre para uso, até comercial

Tags: imagem, aplicação-web, icons, ícone

Estou começando a querer fazer ícones, porém quero fazer da forma correta. Tenho uma dúvida. Como eu posso saber se uma fonte está disponível para uso no geral.

Nem sei se aqui é o lugar ideal para postar isso, mas vamos lá.

Por exemplo. Estou usando a sans-serif, para fazer ícones, fiz um do facebook agora, é certo fazer isso? No caso como eu poderia arrumar uma fonte `public domain` para que eu possa inserir nos meus futuros ícones. Essa `sans-serif` é daquelas `liberation sans`?

Alguém tem alguma dica para que eu não me preocupe com isso no futuro quando eu for fazer ícones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Stack Overflow em Português tem certas perguntas relacionadas a desenvolvimento, mas que não são sobre programação em si, devido ao fato de que os stacks em português ainda serem bem recentes em relação aos stacks em geral. Em inglês, você pode perguntar no [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). Nele há inclusive uma pergunta semelhante à sua:

[How do I know if my downloaded font is legal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16469/how-do-i-know-if-my-downloaded-font-is-legal) ("Como sei se posso utilizar legalmente a fonte que baixei")

E a resposta é que cada caso é um caso. Você deve pesquisar a licença individual de cada fonte. Infelizmente isso é um trabalho que você deve fazer para cada fonte diferente que for utilizar. Mas talvez você consiga encontrar alguma lista curada para as fontes mais comumente utilizadas.

Cada autor publica suas fontes com uma licença diferente. Em geral, quem utiliza Creative Commons as libera para uso não comercial sem necessidade de pagamento, mas para uso comercial você pode ter que pagar uma licença.

Agora... *Sans-serif* não é uma fonte, é uma característica que várias fontes têm em comum. *Sans-serif* significa "sem [serifas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serifa)", que são uma marcação visual que facilita a leitura para algumas pessoas.

Várias fontes tem *Sans-serif* no nome, para já deixar claro que não possuem serifas, mas só isso não define o nome. Descubra o nome da sua fonte e verifique como seus autores a disponibilizam para uso livre ou comercial.

Comment: Eu até sabia que sans-serif é uma característica, devo estar confuso. http://imgur.com/n8fSmKh

Comment: Fiquei com essa dúvida de novo, e olha aqui do que eu estava falando, sobre `sans-serif` https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/microsoft-sans-serif/licensing.html

Comment: @MarceloRafael `Microsoft Sans Serif` é o nome completo da fonte. Existem outras fontes que também tem `Sans Serif` no nome.

Answer (score 2):

Olha amigo você pode acessar a biblioteca de fontes do google. La todas são gratuitas e acredito que não surgira problemas futuros.

https://fonts.google.com/